# How to power this LED array

Tags: led, wiring

I have this infra-red LED array that I took from an old game camera.  I would like to be able to incorporate this into a Raspberry Pi project (home security camera).  Specifically I would like to turn on the LEDs once the PIR triggers.

I do not know how I would wire these lights.  Any advice is appreciated.

[image: front]

[image: back]

Comment: not a question about Raspberry Pi ... the second picture is blurry and poorly lit ... that is also the more important picture ... please post another ... the printing on bottom components should be legible

Comment: @jsotola - I have updated the bottom components image.